# Selecting more than one value from a check box and showing an element that is different for each value from the check box

Tags: jquery, html

So I have this html code of a check box with multiple selections.

If I select 1, I want to show element1, If I select 2, I want to show element2, If I select 1 and 2 together, show 1 and 2 together.

I'm trying to figure it out with this code, but it's just not working!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nearbyy').bind('change', function(e) {
    if ($('#nearbyy').val() == '1') {
      $("#Airport").show();
      $("#Garden").hide();
    } else if ($('#nearbyy').val() == '2') {
      $("#Airport").hide();
      $("#Garden").show();
    } else if ($('#nearbyy').val() == '1' || $('#nearbyy').val() == '2') {
      $("#Airport").show();
      $("#Garden").show();
    } else {
      $("#Airport").hide();
      $("#Garden").hide();
    }
  }).trigger('change');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>List of Stores which completed the survey so far</label>
  <select multiple="" for="postage" id="nearbyy" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="1" id ="1">Airport</option>
          <option value="2" id ="2">Garden</option>
  </select>


  <br />
  <div id="Airport" class="form-control">
    Element1
  </div>
  <br />

  <div id="Garden" class="form-control">
    Element2
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#nearbyy').val()` returns an array, so you need to check if your values are in that array.

Here is a solution close to your original code. Notice, that you also need to check for occurence of both values at first if you use an `else if` structure.

jquery's `inArray()` method returns `-1` if the value is not in the array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nearbyy').bind('change', function(e) {
    const values = $('#nearbyy').val();
    if (jQuery.inArray("1", values) > -1 && jQuery.inArray("2", values) > -1) {
      $("#Airport").show();
      $("#Garden").show();
    } else if (jQuery.inArray("1", values) > -1) {
      $("#Airport").show();
      $("#Garden").hide();
    } else if (jQuery.inArray("2", values) > -1) {
      $("#Airport").hide();
      $("#Garden").show();
    } else {
      $("#Airport").hide();
      $("#Garden").hide();
    }
  }).trigger('change');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>List of Stores which completed the survey so far</label>
<select multiple for="postage" id="nearbyy" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="1" id ="1">Airport</option>
    <option value="2" id ="2">Garden</option>
</select>


<br />
<div id="Airport" class="form-control">
    Element1
</div>
<br />

<div id="Garden" class="form-control">
    Element2
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Hold **Ctrl** in windows, **Cmd** in mac for multi-select.

For **Multi Select** the value will be in a **Array** format. So you can't match it as a single value. And set the **ID** to your element same as the **option**. So you can directly access the element without **IF Condition**. This is called **Code Optimisation**

```js
$("#nearbyy").change(function(e){

  const value = $(e.target).val(); // value list

  $('.element').hide(); // hide all elements first

  // loop through array
  value.forEach(x => {
    try {
     $('#'+x).show(); // show only selected elements
    } catch(ex) {
      //not select anything or element not found
    }
  })
  

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>List of Stores which completed the survey so far</label>
 <select multiple="" for="postage" id="nearbyy" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="1">Airport</option>
          <option value="2">Garden</option>
  </select>


  <br />
  <div id="1" class="form-control element" style='display:none'>
    Element1
  </div>
  <br />

  <div id="2" class="form-control element" style='display:none'>
    Element2
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score -1):

Try `.css()` instead of `.show()` and `.hide()`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nearbyy').bind('change', function(e) {
    if ($('#nearbyy').val() == '1') {
      $("#Airport").css("display", "unset");
      $("#Garden").css("display", "none");
    } else if ($('#nearbyy').val() == '2') {
      $("#Airport").css("display", "none");
      $("#Garden").css("display", "unset");
    } else if ($('#nearbyy').val() == '1' .val() == '2') {
      $("#Airport").css("display", "unset");
      $("#Garden").css("display", "unset");
    } else {
      $("#Airport").css("display", "none");
      $("#Garden").css("display", "none");
    }
  }).trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

Read more: https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it :)